# How can I upload zip file to forest admin?

Tags: forestadmin

Can I upload a zip file and extract it in Forest admin smart actions?
the documentation has an example for CSV file and it is working fine for me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can definitively use ADM-Zip (https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip), which is a pure JavaScript implementation for zip data (de)compression for NodeJS.